# Ionic Sqlite not running on chrome

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  username='name';
  items = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private sqlite: SQLite) {

  }

  save()
  {
    alert();
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

        //data insert section
        db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usernameList(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name)', {})
          .then(() => alert('Executed SQL'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));

        //data insert section
        db.executeSql('INSERT INTO usernameList(name) VALUES(?)', [this.username])
          .then(() => alert('Executed SQL'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));

        //data retrieve section
        db.executeSql('select * from usernameList', {}).then((data) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));

          //alert(data.rows.length);
          //alert(data.rows.item(5).name);
          this.items = [];
          if(data.rows.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
              //alert(data.rows.item(i).name);�
              this.items.push({name: data.rows.item(i).name});
            }
          }

        }, (err) => {
          alert('Unable to execute sql: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        });
      })
      .catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
  }
}
```

Why I am not able to test my code on broswe

I even try using **ionic cordova run browser**

This is my console error

> OPEN database:
>   data.db cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found for
>   :: SQLitePlugin :: close cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found
>   for :: SQLitePlugin :: open
>   plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:196 OPEN database:
>   data.db FAILED, aborting any pending transactions
>   plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:174 OPEN database:
>   data.db cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found for ::
>   SQLitePlugin :: close cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found for
>   :: SQLitePlugin :: open
>   plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:196 OPEN database:
>   data.db FAILED, aborting any pending transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql doesnot support on ionic for testing on browser. Cordova doesnot support it. You need to test in native app

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not meant to be used on non-"native" builds of your Ionic app:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/ - see the platforms listed there and there is no "browser" as supported platform.

To test it you should run your app on a device via something like:
ionic cordova run android

Depending on your use case & your requirements for local persistence sometimes it make sense to use Ionic Storage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/ which can use sqlite and can "fallback" / use another type of persistence that is supported by a browser (websql, indexeddb). In this case you can develop and test your app in browser using "ionic serve" and then later on validate that it also works fine on a real device.

Comment: what do you mean studio?

Comment: i mean android studio emulator